# Restrict viewing of database events to currently logged on user .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using this code, from the nerddinner example. This method will display a list of all the upcoming dinners in a database when called in the controller.

```
public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners()
{
    return from dinner in entities.Dinners
           where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now
           orderby dinner.EventDate
           select dinner;
}
```

I would have thought that this:

```
public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners()
{
    return from dinner in entities.Dinners
           where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now && dinner.HostedBy == User.Identity.Name
           orderby dinner.EventDate
           select dinner;
}
```

would give me just the dinners that are hosted by the currently logged on user, however I get three errors:

> 1. Delegate 'System.Func'
>      does not take 1 arguments
> 2. Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>      delegate type
> 3. The name 'User' does not exist in the current context

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated :)

the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.Identity.Name` is only available in the controller. So you might pass it as argument to your method:

```
public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners(string user)
{
    return from dinner in entities.Dinners
           where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now && dinner.HostedBy == user
           orderby dinner.EventDate
           select dinner;
}
```

And when calling this method from within the controller action:

```
var upcomingDinners = dinnerRepository.FindUpcomingDinners(User.Identity.Name);
```

Also make sure that the user needs to be authenticated to call this controller action (`[Authorize]` attribute) or you might get an exception if an anonymous user tries to call it.